# How to read from an already existing dropdown list and then click on a button using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Please tell me how to read from an already existing dropdown list and then click on OK using AUTOHOTKEY. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Window Spy utility in AutoHotkey to see if there is an associated ClassNN control value associated with your dropdown list.  If there is a control value available you will possibly be able to read the selection of the dropdown list (probably not the entire contents of the list, since those items that are not selected will not be returned using `ControlGet`)

As for clicking ok, you can either use the `Click` command where the mouse moves and clicks the button based on a set of coordinates (referenced either to the screen or to the window--use Window Spy to determine the right coordinates), or use the same method above with Window Spy to find the control's ClassNN ID and send it a click programmatically using `ControlSend`